# charts_flutter : Display Column Chart Y Axis Labels in Kilo(K), Million(M)

Tags: flutter, dart

How to display values like 50000 as 50K, 5000000 as 5M in charts_flutter Like below[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.
inside your build method add a valueformatter and dont forget to import the below code

```flutter
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final valueFormatter =
        charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec.fromNumberFormat(
            NumberFormat.compact());
```

and add this valueFormatter inside the chart

```flutter
     charts.TimeSeriesChart(
                seriesList,
                animate: animate,
                primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                  
                  tickFormatterSpec: valueFormatter,

                dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
              )),
```